# Test Tube babies

Tags: practical-islam, halal-haram, sunni, fiqh

There are various methods in [Assisted reproductive technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_reproductive_technology) i.e. IUI, IVF, ICSI and further variances of ICSI. It is stated [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_response_to_ART) that

> The Islamic community, after the fatwa on ART by Gad El-Hak Ali Gad
>   El-Hak of Egypt's Al-Azhar University, largely accepted ART

Is there any difference of opinion as far as Sunni, especially Deobandi, school of thought is concerned?

Answer (score 5):

There is basic rule in Islam that as long as certain set of actions do not go against islamic teachings, then they are allowed.

In case of Artificial insemination, it is of 2 types,

- in which Sperm and ovum is taken from husband and wife themselves, and not from anyone else, it is allowed without any problem , but STILL being in bounds of islam.
- In which sperm or ovum is taken from someone else, besides husband or wife, which is haram by all ways.

Also, Surrogacy is haram as well.

So, IUI , IVF are fine, and ISCI is part of IVF.

For scholarly reference:

http://spa.qibla.com/issue_view.asp?HD=7&ID=2455&CATE=2