# Is IVF with Sperm donation or Egg donation prohibited in islam?

Tags: halal-haram, zina, pregnancy, adultery

Earlier I read in many articles that IVF is haraam since it is an unnatural way. But now its considered OK but only with the fusion of sperm-egg of a married couple.
I have a doubt that why is pregnancy considered haraam using egg donation or sperm donation, and considered to be `zinaa`.
As far as I know (not very sure) `zinaa` of the body is to GET PHYSICAL with someone you are not married to (adultery). So in egg/sperm donation, people are not getting physical, so how could we term it as `zinaa` ?
Also, if a lady isn't getting pregnant naturally, and to avoid her divorce would it be wrong to go for egg/sperm donation ? Because no matter how loving you are, an adopted child would always be an adopted child, as he deserves to know his lineage. Once he knows his actual parents, its very likely that the love won't be the same.
Also, isn't getting a child with egg/sperm donation better than getting a divorce (divorce is a thing that Allah s.w.t hates most). ?

Comment: Somewhat related [Test-tube fertilization after death of the husband](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29759/can-a-woman-use-test-tube-fertilization-after-the-death-of-her-husband), [Purification after test-tube fertilization]( http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28894/which-form-of-purification-is-necessary-after-test-tube-fertilization), [Selling off women ovum]( http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32623/selling-off-women-ovum) and [Test-tube babies](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10486/test-tube-babies)

Answer (score 1):

You start your assumptions from the wrong perspective and we know logic says: ex falso quodlibet.

Zina is indeed a sexual relationship out of marriage.

Now what you seem to have overseen is that in the case of an in-vitro fertilization where the eggs don't come from the wife (while the semen comes from the husband), they would come from an other woman. This woman is a foreigner of the husband, so any child that would come out of this fertilization by shari'a is not the wife's child, but the husband's child only.
And here we have a major fiqh Issue: Because a child which comes from a legal relationship should have the name of the father ([33:5](http://legacy.quran.com/33/5), and in the [sunnah](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/61/18)), a child which comes from an illegal relationship should have the name of the woman (from sunnah a [clear statement](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/13/91) and a [bit ambiguous](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6818) one), now the woman who was pregnant with the child is the wife of the father (note the later hadith even says that a child of a married woman is given the name of the husband), and of course the father of a typical zina child can accept his fatherhood and give it his name, but because of the facts from above it would be considered as a children from a zina relationship, as the semen of the husband have been introduced in the egg of a foreign woman. It is not zina between the husband and an other woman, but a production of a zina child, which is the main issue here!

Also an other problem is the fact that this child in fact has two mothers is an issue and one of the [goals of shari'a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maqasid)مقاصد الشريعة  is to keep (the cleanness of) or preserve the lineage and the whole of what I've mentioned shows that the lineage matter here is ambiguous which is against shari'a!

Note that even in case that this woman who has donated an egg or ovum was an other wife of the husband scholars rather consider this procedure as rather haram. While it is perfectly halal if the fertilzation has been performed in a laboratory as long as the donated ovum(s) and sperms come from the married couple.

Here some sources for the child naming and attribution issue [islamqa #85043](https://islamqa.info/en/85043) [#33591](https://islamqa.info/en/33591) and in Arabic see for example [islamweb #6045](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/6045).

Of course divorce is the worst solution, but I know of many husbands who didn't even consider to marry another wife (for the sake of having offspring) and even treated their infertile wife in the best manners. So one must just accept the fact that we may be given children, may be given only girls or only boys or Allah may for reasons (HE only knows) deny us the luck and joy of having own kids ([42:49-50](http://legacy.quran.com/42/49-50)). Aren't we asked to obey Allah and have faith? Maybe this is for our best (2:216):

> ... But perhaps you hate a thing and it is good for you; and perhaps you love a thing and it is bad for you. And Allah Knows, while you know not.

On the other hand an adopted child when treated the same as an own child in general would act more or less the same as an own child so either it would hold those people whom brought it up or cared for it a long time in honor or just would act as any other disobedient child.