# Are Muslim women allowed to donate their Eggs?

Tags: quran, hadith

Assalamualaikum,
Are Muslim women allowed to donate their Eggs? I saw that women have around 400,000 eggs, but can they donate -8-10 like donating blood.

*Eggs which then other women who can't have children use to have children.

Comment: Take a look at this question/answer. https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36445/37617